# Integer promotion in C operation

Tags: c, math, integer

```c
uint64_t impulses = 4000000;
uint16_t impulses_per_meter = 999;
uint32_t meters = impulses / impulses_per_meter;
```

As I understand the `impulses_per_meter` gets an integer promotion before calculating the final value of the operation `impulses / impulses_per_meter`, then the result gets truncated to `uint16_t`.

Is my understanding correct or the result might be incorrect?

By the way, the MCU I'm running this on is 8 bit.

Comment: What would be the point? It's the same result anyway. The quotient is 64-bit and gets truncated to 32 bits.

Comment: [This (long) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/898348) might help

Comment: If the processor can't use a 16-bit divisor, it would have to be promoted.

Comment: OT: the third assignment would most likely trigger a warning because a 64 bit type is being converted to a 32 bit type and loss of information might occur.

Comment: For robust code, `if(impulses_per_meter == 0 || impulses / impulses_per_meter > UINT32_MAX) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: "then the result gets truncated to uint16_t." Why would it be truncated to 16 bits? You probably mean 32 bits. Correct?

Answer (score 3):

There is a part of the standard called "usual arithmetic conversions". Its aim is to determine a common type when the operands of arithmetic operations differ in type and signedness.

When both operands are integers (as is your case), they both undergo integer promotion. After promotion, if both operands are the same type (`int`), then that is the type of the expression. If they are different but have the same signedness, the standard says:

> If the types have the same signedness (both signed or both unsigned), the operand whose type has the lesser conversion rank is implicitly converted to the other type.

In your case, this would mean that `impulses_per_meter` is implicitly converted to `unsigned long long` (assuming a data model where `uint64_t` is the same as `unsigned long long`).

However, assigning that expression result (`uint64_t`) to `meters` (`uint32_t`) involves truncation and data loss. A modern compiler should issue a warning and you should change your code.

Answer (score 3):

In the expression `impulses / impulses_per_meter`:

- Normally, implicit integer promotion is carried out on both operands of `/` (and most other such binary operators) as the first step of "the usual arithmetic conversions".
- On an 8 bit system, `int` is 16 bit. `impulses_per_meter` is already of a type `uint16_t` with equal conversion rank as `int`, so no integer promotion is required. `impulses` is of type `uint64_t` so no promotion there either.
- The next step of "the usual arithmetic conversions" is to convert `impulses_per_meter` to the same type as the operand of `/` with the greatest conversion rank, in this case to `uint64_t`.
- The division is carried out on `uint64_t` types and the result is of type `uint64_t`.
- During assignment to `uint32_t`, the result of the division gets converted from `uint64_t` to `uint32_t`. If the result can't fit in one, you will lose data.

For details check out [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

As a side note, using 64 bit arithmetic on a 8 bit MCU is a horrible idea. 64 bit division in particular is spectacularly inefficient. `4000000` fits inside a `uint32_t` so I'm not sure what you are even doing here.